# window.location search path doesn't work

Tags: search, window.location

The following search function navigates to : 
**http://webbsite.com/?search=query**
instead of 
**http://webbsite.com/search?q=query**

```
           this._search = function (evt) {
        var searchValue = this.select('searchTextSelector').val();
        if (searchValue !== '' && evt.which === 13 /*enter*/) {
            var query = this._getValFromEventObject(evt);
            window.location.href = '/search?q=' + query;
        }
    };
```

How do I change the window.location path ?

Ok sorry, I solved it by adding e.preventDefault();

Comment: window.location.href doesn't even fire..

Comment: Why don't you use Response.Redirect method instead of windows.location?

Answer (score 0):

fixed by adding e.preventDefault();